# Convert string column to int pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a Dataframe that has a column with unique string column. like below:

```
id   customerId               ...
1    vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn
2    KaLEhwzZxCQ7GjPmVwBVav
3    pybDYgTiCUv3Pv3WLgxKCM
4    zqPiDV33KwrMBZoyeQXMJW
5    CR8z3ThPyzBKXFqqzemQAS
.
```

I want to replace customerIDs to int by a method like

```
# replace dataFrame.customerId[from start to end]
dataFrame.customerId.replace(sum(map(ord, ???)))
```

How can i do that?

Comment: please post your expected output

Comment: a `sum(map(ord, ...))` isn't guaranteed to give you a unique value for each Id. In fact if you have two  id's that are anagrams of each other, you'll get the exact same id with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UID'], index=range(7))
df.iloc[0,0] = 'vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn'
df.iloc[1,0] = 'KaLEhwzZxCQ7GjPmVwBVav'
df.iloc[2,0] = 'pybDYgTiCUv3Pv3WLgxKCM'
df.iloc[3,0] = 'zqPiDV33KwrMBZoyeQXMJW'
df.iloc[4,0] = 'CR8z3ThPyzBKXFqqzemQAS'
df.iloc[5,0] = 'zqPiDV33KwrMBZoyeQXMJW'  # equal to 3
df.iloc[6,0] = 'vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn'  # equal to 0
```

PS: I added 2 `UID`s equal to previous ones to see that they'll be correctly categorized

you can use a categorical `type`

```
df['UID_categorical'] = df.UID.astype('category').cat.codes
```

output

```
                      UID  UID_categorical
0  vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn                3
1  KaLEhwzZxCQ7GjPmVwBVav                1
2  pybDYgTiCUv3Pv3WLgxKCM                2
3  zqPiDV33KwrMBZoyeQXMJW                4
4  CR8z3ThPyzBKXFqqzemQAS                0
5  zqPiDV33KwrMBZoyeQXMJW                4
6  vqUkxUDuEmB7gHWQvcYrBn                3
```

where `UID_categorical` is `int`

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   UID              7 non-null      object
 1   UID_categorical  7 non-null      int8  
dtypes: int8(1), object(1)
memory usage: 191.0+ bytes
```

If you want to replace just do

```
df['UID'] = df.UID.astype('category').cat.codes
```